# Parsing a list from android sqlite to remote database using a loop

Tags: php, android, sql, json, sqlite

Part of the android app I am building requires me to save a list of users in an sqlite database. The user can then enter an activity which shows the list of users currently stored in the sqlite datebase within a listview.

I have then tried to implement a function to sync this list of users to a remote database, using Async Tasks, JSON, and a PHP service, by using a FOR LOOP to cycle through the database tables *'users'*.

The problem is that the sync only works for the first item in the list. After this has been passed through to the remote database, the activity crashes. 
The log reads:

E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value data of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
    Process: example.prguru.com.pi_prototype_30, PID: 5139
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
...

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object reference
            at example.prguru.com.pi_prototype_30.ShowAdmins$syncUser.doInBackground(ShowAdmins.java:137)
            at example.prguru.com.pi_prototype_30.ShowAdmins$syncUser.doInBackground(ShowAdmins.java:87)

Line 137 in the java code is:

```
 Log.d("Sync Attempt", jobj.toString());
```

**PHP CODE:**

```
require_once 'config.php';

if(!empty($_POST)){
$row = $_POST['table_id'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$id_num = $_POST['id_number'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email  = $_POST['email'];
$course = $_POST['course'];
$password = $_REQUEST['password'];

$ins = mysql_query("INSERT INTO pi_prototype_inventory_30.users (table_id, type, id_number, name, email, course, password) 
VALUES('$row','$type','$id_num','$name', '$email', '$course', '$password')");

if(!$ins)
{
    echo (mysql_error());
}
else
{
    echo ("data inserted");
}
}
else {
echo (mysql_error());
}
```

**SYNC CLASS:**

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Check for success tag
        int success;

        DBHandler dbAdapter = DBHandler.getDBHandlerInstance(getApplicationContext());
        try {
            dbAdapter.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("*** select ", e.getMessage());
        }

        dbAdapter.openDataBase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM users";
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> stringList = dbAdapter.selectRecordsFromDBList(query, null);
        dbAdapter.close();

        try {

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(7);
            for (int i = 0; i < stringList.size(); i++) {
                ArrayList<String> list = stringList.get(i);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("table_id", list.get(0)));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", list.get(1)));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_number", list.get(2)));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", list.get(3)));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", list.get(4)));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("course", list.get(5)));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", list.get(6)));

                Log.d("Request!", "Starting!");

                jobj = jsonParser.makeObjHttpRequest(REG_URL, "POST", nameValuePairs);

                Log.d("Sync Attempt", jobj.toString());

            }//forLoop
                success = jobj.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1){
                    Log.d("SYNCED!", jobj.toString());
                    return jobj.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }
                else {
                    Log.d("Sync failure!", jobj.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return jobj.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }



        } catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }//doInBackground
```

**JSON PARSER CLASS:**

```
public JSONObject makeObjHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                  List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method.equals("POST")){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method.equals("GET")){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        Log.i("tagconvertstr", "["+json+"]");
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

Do I need to implement some sort of loop in my PHP code so it accepts more than one entry from the list? I don't know how I would go about coding that because I will never be sure how many entries will need to be synced at any one time. Or is the problem within the java code itself? I'm not quite sure how to make sense of the errors presented in the log.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException` -- do you know what a NullPointerException is?

Comment: Yes, I do - it means it isn't pointing to anything. But why would jobj be null? I have initialised it in the onCreate method as a new JSONObject, and I have given it a value in this code jobj = jsonParser.makeObjHttpRequest(REG_URL, "POST", nameValuePairs);

Comment: Can that method return null?

Comment: That's the way I have it set up in another similar app, and it works fine - the return null doesn't affect it. So I'm not sure why it wouldn't be able to return null in this app.

Comment: Working in another app does not prove it's working your app. If `.makeObjHttpRequest()` can return null, then `jobj` can be null and the call to `toString()` will result in a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood what you were asking. No .makeObjHttpRequest() should return json. I'll edit my question to include my jsonParser class.

Comment: The parser code you posted does not compile. It is missing variable declaration for `is`, `json`, and `jObj`.

Comment: No, it isn't - they are declared at the beginning of the class. I have posted the relevant method in the above question.

Answer (score 0):

Your parser is returning a null object. Logcat is pretty clear about this. First there is this message:

```
E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value data of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

This matches exactly what's in one of your catch blocks in the parser:

```
try {
    Log.i("tagconvertstr", "["+json+"]");
    jObj = new JSONObject(json);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString()); // <- HERE
}
```

If an exception is thrown in this block, `jObj` will not be assigned. If you want the parser to never return null, then you need to assign `jObj` in the catch block. Otherwise, your other code needs to check that the value returned is not null before trying to use it.